# blake2b length extension attack approach

Tags: hash, length-extension, blake2

I understand that a completion flag parameter with Boolean value of 1 is used by Blake2 when it’s compressing the final block of the digested message.

This ensures that one cannot load the state of a blake2 implementation with a blake2 digest and continue on (length extension attack).

However I was just thinking, given that blake2 is open source, couldn't one just create a variant of blake2 that doesn't contain the completion flag, run the original message through it to obtain a non 'completed' digest and then use this as the state to mount a length extension attack through the standard version of blake2?

Which seems so trivial, I'm surprised we consider it length extension proof.

Surely loading the state of SHA-256 is only slightly more hassle than forking blake2, modifying and loading the state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BLAKE2 is not open-source. BLAKE2 is a specification.

The state is shuffled one last time after having set the final bit, ensuring that a small change, even a single bit, yields a completely different output, that cannot be reverted.

A length extension attack means that knowing `M` and `Hk(M)`, you may be able to compute `Hk(M||E)` without knowing the key `k`.

But with BLAKE2, in order to compute `Hk(M)` before the finalization, you would need to know the key `k`. If you somehow know the secret key, you can already forge tags for arbitrary messages.